# How to change the texture on dulce de leche?

Tags: dulce-de-leche

I recently made dulce de leche using the can in boiling water method.  It came out tasting delicious but it was way to runny. I boiled it for two hours and used sweetened condensed milk and was expecting something that would be able to hold up a spoon. Instead, it was more like a thin sauce. Anyway how do I fix this? or is this the way that it is supposed to come out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The texture is controlled simply by time; 2 hours isn't enough. Try 3 to 4 hours. Or use a pressure cooker, it goes much faster in there - about 45 minutes should do it.

Comment: +1 for the pressure cooker, that how my mom has always made it.

Comment: So, now that the can is opened, how are we supposed to fix it and get the creamy texture? Is it possible to let the can boil for another two hours with opened lid?