# Can I combine two methods of making Dulce de leche from a can of sweetened condensed milk?

Tags: dulce-de-leche

As I gather, there are various methods of making Dulce de leche from a can of sweetened condensed milk. I've actually tried boiling the can for 3-4 hours twice, and the results not entirely to my satisfaction. I don't get the caramelized dark color. As I opened the can, and the color was lighter than expected, I did let the can boil for another hour but no significant changes in color was observed! Today I was googling to find out more about this method, I get familiar with another method which is to make Delce de leche in the oven. So what I want to know is, is it possible to put the undone dulce de leche I made in the pot two days ago in the oven to finally achieve the desired caramelized and dark color?

[This question is quite informative](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6273/how-to-change-the-texture-on-dulce-de-leche), but not very helpful solution-wise.

Comment: I've never made it, but I would think that if the recipe called for putting the sealed can in the oven, you'd have two differences as it's no longer a sealed container -- pressure and evaporative loss.

Comment: @Joe: Actually [the recipe calls for pouring the contents of the can of sweetened into a baking dish](http://thetoughcookie.com/2014/01/17/making-dulce-de-leche-oven-method/). The question is, will it work if the can was simmered for two hours beforehand?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't use oven method, but you might want to reduce the cooking time, since it's already partially caramelized.

Comment: If you're pouring it into a baking dish first, the cooking time is less important: you can just keep an eye on it and watch for the proper color.